# Complex event processing with flexible and dynamic event pattern

Tags: events, real-time, rule, complex-event-processing

This is a general question on Complex Event Processing.

Is it possible to make a complete generic CEP component with a user interface, where users can define their own rules and system does work.

To put it in another

Does it make any sense to do something like that. What is the standard principle for CEP engines. Are they tailored for specific purpose ? or usually generic?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with others but on [Evam Streaming Analytics](http://evam.com/), which I am one of the developers, we are developing a CEP engine along with a GUI application that lets user design their custom logic and run that on engine.

So I can say that it makes sense :)